# How to check if multidimensional array row contains non-Zero value

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, while-loop, row

Just a short question regarding multidimensional arrays in C#.

How can I check if one row of a multidimensional array contains a non-Zero value?
In Matlab, the "any"-command does exactly what I need.

Finally I need to put the request into a while condition. Means in Matlab: while(any(array[1,2,:])) --> which means: while(any-entry-of-the-row-is-not-Zero)...

I tried already the Array.Exists() or Array.Find() but it seems to work only with one-dimensional arrays.

Thanks

Comment: show some code please ? i want to know the type of array ?

Comment: just a `foreach` and if statement would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options

```
myMultiArray.Any(row => row.Contains(Something));
```

or as Sriram Sakthivel Suggested

```
foreach(var row in myMultiArray)
    if(row.Contains(Something)
        //Found it!

foreach(var row in myMultiArray)
    if(row.IndexOf(Something) >= 0)
        //Found it!
```

More spefically to your question

```
myMultiArray.Any(row => row.Any(cell => cell != 0));

foreach(var row in myMultiArray)
    foreach(var cell in myMultiArray)
        if(cell != 0)
            //Found it!

for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
         if(array[i,j] != 0)
             //Do Something
```

MSDN Information

[Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).ASPX)

[IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer...

Actually the Any command would be great, but I can't use it cause i generated a int[,,] array. I can use the foreach-possibility. I would have to work with List<List<int>> if I would like to use the C# Any-Command, right?

Comment: No worries, hope it helps

Comment: @Krus - The Any Command works on an IEnumerable which an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx) is, so no, you shouldn't need to use a list

Comment: With a one-dimensional array it works, but as soon as I change the array to an int[,] array, I can't use the Any-Command anymore...

Comment: @Krus - I got confused with 2d arrays and multidimentional ones earlier (had a coffee now!) I've attached some code that should do what you are looking for (without linq)