# Checking values inside a 2D array

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a 2 dimensional array `int[][] data` and i want to see if the value contains the value `45` for example

I created this line of code

```
bool contains = data.Where(x => x.Contains(45)).ToArray().Count() != 0 ? true : false;
```

but it looks like there is unnecessary code and I am sure that there is an easier or more efficient way to do this

Comment: Well the `.ToArray().Count() != 0` can be replaced by `.Any()`, but more importantly we can't guess what does make you happy. Please read [ask] and try to edit this into an actually answerable question, and share your research.

Comment: @CodeCaster well using toarray,count and then another function or check to verify if it isnt 0 seems a but long obviously this is what makes me unhappy :/ dont know how this is confusing to you

Comment: What is confusing to me is what you expect of this question. _"Here is some code that makes me unhappy"_ isn't really answerable. Do you want people to post random snippets of code that essentially does the same as your code, but which makes you "happy"? Why don't you start by listing the things that make you happy then? Did you try reading [ask] and sharing your research by [edit]ing your question? Did you find [How to check if multidimensional array row contains non-Zero value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562496/), for example?

Comment: Event though the question was solved, you do realize that you can remove the { ? true : false } in your sample and it would be exactly the same right? no need for it.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok i removed the word unhappy. are you happy?

Comment: Am not. You still asked a question that has been asked many times before, did not share your research and got upvotes and your answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `data` is *not* an array of `int`, it is an array `int[]`
2. the ternary operator takes a `bool` condition and returns a value based on the `bool` value. So `x ? true : false` is the same as `x`. There is no need for the operator.

So what (I assume) you want is not to check if `data` contains `45`, but if *any of the arrays in `data` contains 45*. So you either flatten the jagged array into on enumeration using `SelectMany` or concat two `Any` calls:

```
bool contains = data.SelectMany(d => d).Contains(45);
```

or

```
bool contains = data.Any(d => d.Contains(45);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Any` linq extension.

```
bool exists = data.SelectMany(x=>x).Any(x=>x == 45);
```

Or

```
bool exists = data.Any(x=>x.Any(s=>s == 45));
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.IndexOf` is optimised for integer arrays, so if your inner arrays are long and you care about speeding it up that much it might be worth doing it like this:

```
bool exists = data.Any(a => Array.IndexOf(a, 45) != -1);
```

Comment: An `int[]` is an `ICollection<int>`. `Enumerable.Contains<T>` calls the `ICollection<T>.Contains` method if the source is an `ICollection<T>`. So in the version `data.Any(a => a.Contains(45))` the `Contains` method of array is used, and this is as well optimized as `IndexOf`. But good point that this will be a little bit better than the `SelectMany` version. Though I think it's only a micro-optimization even for very large arrays (but I did not measure it).

Comment: Thank you this was noted